# Problem with inserting images in two columns paper

Tags: graphics, columns

I have just started using LateX and i am writing my first paper in it. 
My question is that when i insert an image in PDF format, there is few lines of white spaces in between the text and the image. I want to get rid of it somehow as i am not able to control the position of the page image and when i increase the scale size, it jumps to the next page. 
I am using two columns paper writing format. The way i am doing is given below:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.075]{Dualhop1}
\caption{A single Dual-hop Backhaul Network Model}
\label{Figure. 1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Try running `pdfcrop` on your image to ensure there's no border in the pdf itself. (Also, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.)

Comment: Hi Sean, the pdfcrop worked. Thank you. I am glad that i didn't switched back to MS Word as it is very difficult and gets irritating if you are new to it. Anyways, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image might have a border of its own.  To remove it, you can use the `pdfcrop` program included in the major TeX distributions:

```sh
$ ls
paper.tex my-figure.pdf
$ pdfcrop my-figure.pdf
$ ls
paper.tex my-figure.pdf my-figure-crop.pdf
```

Use `my-figure-crop` in your TeX document instead of `my-figure`.  (Of course, you can simply delete the old and rename the new, too.)

Comment: HI, Where exactly i should include this in my TeX document ?

Comment: Simply use the new `my-figure-crop.pdf` document instead of `my-figure.pdf`. These commands are done in a terminal (aka command prompt) outside of TeX.